# Finding out, whether Bluetooth is enabled or not on an iPod/iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, bluetooth, ipod

I'm writing an app, that automatically finds peers running the same app, so I need the Bluetooth-device.
But because of app-restrictions I'm not allowed to use the private framework to enable, or activate the Bluetooth-device.
I'd rather avoid a pointless searching for peers if there's no possibility of finding them.

Is there any way to find out, whether it is already activated, so I could at least throw an error message?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the [Game Kit Framework reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GameKit_Collection/GameKit_Collection.pdf)?

According to Apple:

> Game Kit offers your applications the
>   ability to create Bluetooth
>   connections between two devices.

Comment: Yes and GK is used in the app, but it cannot produce any real results without bluetooth. If the user has disabled bluetooth on his iPhone/iPod, then the search for peers goes on forever, which is something I'd rather avoid.

Comment: I have implemented something similar and ran into the same problem. I have a client and server network architecture setup, but when you start as a server, gamekit doesn't check if bluetooth is enabled. However if you are a client, gamekit does check and asks the player to enable bluetooth.